# Python IndexError: what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to search a string containing dates, so i have to find substrings that match formats (date_text1, date_text2 and date_text) and munge them into a conventional format such as 25/04/1955.

Why does the index not exist?

```
import re 

#date_text1 = '042555'
#date_text2 = '04/25/1955'
date_text = 'April 25, 1955'

date_patterns = (r'(\d{2}) (\d{2}) (\d{2})', r'(\d{2}) / (\d{2}) / (\d{4})', r'([\w\D]+) (\d{2}) , (\d{4})')

scan = True
idx = 0
while scan:
    match = re.fullmatch(date_patterns[idx], date_text)
    if match:
        month, day, year = match.groups()
        scan = False
    else:
        idx += 1

# Adjust for years
if int(year) <= 19:
    year = "20"+year
elif int(year) <= 99:
    year = "19"+year

# Adjust for months
months = {"January":"01", "February":"02", "March":"03", "April":"04", "May":"05", "June":"06","July":"07", "August":"08", "September":"09", "October":"10","November":"11", "December":"12"}
if len(month) > 2:
    month = months[month]

normalized_date = f'{day}/{month}/{year}'
print(normalized_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because none of your patterns ever match, the loop will keep incrementing the `idx` until it goes over the bounds of the tuple.

The reason for no match, is that you have a small error in your last regex pattern. This:

```
r'([\w\D]+) (\d{2}) , (\d{4})')
```

should be:

```
r'([\w\D]+) (\d{2}), (\d{4})')
```

After fixing this I'm able get the correct output from the program:

> ```
> 25/04/1955
> ```